# How do I get sound to play in an animation I created in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I managed to create this application that includes an animation in it. But I want to make it stand out and more fun by adding a .wav file that I downloaded from the web. I want the sound to play for the duration of the animation. Only started coding a month ago so any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Please show us code examples and anything you have tried that has not worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AVAudioPlayer

just create a method and connect it to your button or animation

```
-(void) playLoopingMusicInApplication {
        AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

    // set the pathForResource: to the name of the sound file, and ofType: to AAC preferrably.
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"WAV"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];

    player.delegate = self;

    //infinite
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [player play];
    //[player release];
}
```

- PS - You will need to get the AVFoundation framework, and the AudioToolbox framework in your project

hope this helps!

Comment: that was very great. Another question please: how to i create a method to connect it to my animation?